# Changing a PHP variable value using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a PHP variable which then passes its value to an SQL/PDO query and shows me the needed results. I want to be able to change that value dynamically with the help of AJAX. I've tried different combinations but I can't get to change that value. Here's what I've got so far:

**home.php**

```
$tsize = $_POST['tsize'];
$prodsize = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM templates WHERE tsize=?");
$prodsize->execute(array($tsize));
```

**Changesize function**

```
function changeSize(tsize){
var tsize = tsize;
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var data = tsize;
xhr.open("POST", "home.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);    
}
```

The function is called from a dropdown menu and the results are shown. If I hardcode the $tsize value in home.php, the results are shown correctly. I've tested what values "tsize" and "data" get and they are in order. However I can't send them to home.php. Is there something wrong with my code? I also have two home.php - one for view and one controller, maybe they interact causing problems?

Edit* Seems to me my index.php gives a problem "ERROR - File not found!!!", I can see it in my Firebug console.

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
$all_url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = explode('/', $all_url[0]);

//Homepage
if (empty($url[1])) {
$url[1] = 'frontpage';
}

//DB connect
$config = array(
'host' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB SERVER
'user' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB USER
'password' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB PASSWORD
'database' => 'xxx' //CHANGE THIS, DB NAME
);
$DB = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'],   $config['user'], $config['password']);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$DB->exec("SET names utf8");

if (file_exists('controller/' . $url[1] . '.php')) {

$gtpl = 'main';
$restricted = array('cart', 'home');

if (!isset($_SESSION['firstVisit']) && $url[1]!='frontpage') {
    $_SESSION['firstVisit'] = false; //ensures we never enter this clause again
    require 'controller/frontpage.php';
}else if (empty($_SESSION['uid']) && in_array($url[1], $restricted)) {
    //not logged in, but trying to access restricted page.
    require 'controller/login.php';
}else{
    require 'controller/' . $url[1] . '.php';
}

require 'view/' . $gtpl . '.php';
} else {
echo 'ERROR - File not found!!!';

}
```

Comment: `var data = 'tsize=' + tsize;`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The "tsize" column in my SQL has numeric values like 4, 7, 20 etc. Setting the data variable like that gets me something like tsize=20. I don't know if that is what I want to be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to send key part in ajax request that is `tsize`, use this;

```
function changeSize(tsize){
    var tsize = tsize;
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var data = "tsize=" + tsize;
    xhr.open("POST", "home.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(data);    
}
```

Comment: I have placed an "echo" right under my code but it shows nothing after the function is executed

Comment: You see ajax request in console?

Comment: But that means home.php not found? Could you please check file existence and permission to read

Comment: The file exists, but I thing the problem is because of a piece of code I have, posted it on my main question if you can look at it.

Comment: But you are sending ajax request to home.php ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not naming the parameter.  When you use POST, in your send, you need to name the parameter and place its value.

Like this:

```
    xhr.send("uid="+user1);
```

You also should do a check for the ready state prior to sending data.

```
    xhrhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xhrhttp.readyState==4 && xhrhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("alertbar").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```